# Click event is not bound to dynamic elements when appendTo() is used

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I know that for dynamic dom elements I need to use `jQuery.fn.on` or delegate, but if I 'move' the elements container appending to another elements in the dom, the click doesn't work anymore.

Here is the the jsFiddle to reproduce the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/j0L7c51f/

Currently I'm using the following bind method:

```
$('#commoditySelector').on( 'click', 'li.available', function() {
    var cmID = $(this).attr('data-cmid');
    $('#debug').html('commoditySelected: '+ cmID);
});
```

If I comment out the code line where I move the ul element using `appendTo()`, the click event bound works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by your use of `mousemove`, not the delegated event handler, as the HTML is being re-built every single time the mouse moves. This means that the delegated event handler is correctly fired on a clicked element, but that element is immediately removed from the DOM, so the event is cancelled before it propagates up the DOM to be processed.

To fix this issue, use the `mouseenter` event on the `a` instead:

```
$('#commodityCategories li a').mouseenter(function(e) {
    // your code...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j0L7c51f/3/)

Comment: @Rory You're perfectly right! And you know also why if I move the mouse faster over the main three list items, then the dropdown list open and close several times as if the queue is not canceled? I've tried both stop() and clearQueue()

Comment: Yep - you need to call `stop(true)` on the `#commodityList` element on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`: http://jsfiddle.net/j0L7c51f/5/. I also made a couple of tweaks to clear up some repeated selectors.

Comment: Try `.finish()` rather than `.stop()`.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for that - I'd never seen `finish()` in the docs. I guess I should take my own advice and RTFM! :)

Comment: @Giox no problem, glad to help

Comment: @Giox What you could do is accept his answer so he gets his credit and people browsing for questions (like me) know this problem is resolved

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's relatively new (added in 1.9) - I only found it cause I always had to lookup if it was .stop(true,false) or true,true or false,false - none of which ever seemed to work correctly :)   But we use what we know, like that time a few months ago I found out that .toggle had a "new" display parameter - only to find it had been added in v1.3! I'd been avoiding using it without for so long, didn't know it had changed :)